# Windows Phone DataVisualization changing graph colors

Tags: xaml, charts, windows-phone

I am trying to change the color for a pie and column graph, but I have no idea how to do that. can someone please show me or give and example?

my code so far:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0" Background="White">
        <chart:Chart x:Name="PieChart" Foreground="Gray" Title="Part of the Chart Resembling a Video Game Character">
            <chart:Chart.Series>
                <chart:PieSeries
                        IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Label}"
                        DependentValueBinding="{Binding Value}">
                    <chart:PieSeries.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="chart:PieSeries">
                            <Canvas x:Name="PlotArea" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                                <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                                    <RotateTransform Angle="125"/>
                                </Canvas.RenderTransform>
                            </Canvas>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </chart:PieSeries.Template>
                </chart:PieSeries>
            </chart:Chart.Series>
        </chart:Chart>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution hopefully will help someone;

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2009/05/19/chart-tweaking-made-easy-how-to-make-four-simple-color-tooltip-changes-with-silverlight-wpf-charting.aspx